# Accessing foreign keys from the Django template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

This is my models.py:

```
class dateEvent(models.Model):

    event = models.ForeignKey('Event', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)

class Event(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

view.py:

```
def events_list_view(request):
    events = dateEvent.objects.all()

    context = {
        'dateEvents': dateEvents,
    }

    return render(request, 'events/events_list.html', context)
```

template:

```
{% for event in dateEvents %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ dateEvent.start_date_time }}</td>
      <td><a href="{% url 'event-detail' id=? %}">{{ dateEvent }}</a></td> # I want the event id here
      <td>{{ dateEvent.venue_event }}</td>

{% endfor %}
```

How can I get the `Event` id which is linked to that `dateEvent` in my template? Using `dateEvent.event_set` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think following can solve the problem :
 `dataEvent.event.id`
Let me know if that worked.